# How to know the DB backup storage size for Amazon RDS instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am newbie to AWS and just deployed a demo app as a free tier user. Below is my RDS instance high level information.

[image]

I see that the db automatic backups are happening as shown below.
[image]

I would like to know what is the size of my DB backup storage as a free tier user. I guess the 5 GB shown above is for database storage.

From the Free tier documentation, I have understood that 20 GB database storage and 20 GB  of backup storage is available for single A-Z Micro Instances.

Where can I find my backup storage size?

I am using Postgresql database.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no direct way to determine the snapshot size of an RDS instance

Usually you don't need to worry if the backup retention period is 1 day, as it is free

According to AWS Documentation

> Backup storage is the storage associated with your automated database backups and any user-initiated DB Snapshots you have taken. Increasing your backup retention period or taking DB Snapshots may increase the backup storage consumed by your database. There is no additional charge for backup storage up to 100% of your consumed database storage for an active DB Instance. For example, if you have an active DB Instance with 10GB-month of consumed database storage, we will provide up to 10GB-month of backup storage at no additional charge.

Which means that, if you have allocated 5GB of storage while creating the RDS instance, and lets say you are consuming 1GB of the allocated space, you can approximately take 5 backups.

## References

https://aws.amazon.com/rds/pricing/#Backup_Storage

https://aws.amazon.com/rds/faqs/#automated-backups-database-snapshots

Answer (score 2):

AWS does not currently have a way to determine actual snapshot sizes.

The "5 GB" of storage is your allocated storage for your database, not necessarily the amount of storage actually used by your database.